# Show different menu's for admin and user

Tags: php, menu, bootstrap-4, nav, user-roles

I want to show different menu links for admin and user roles, below is what I currently have but it shows User Dashboard and Lessons when logged in as admin and when logged in as user it shows all the same menu links, can someone help please with the coding and have a quick look over it as not sure how to go about the best way to do it? Thank you in advance

```
     <nav class="sidebar-nav">
                <ul id="sidebarnav">
                    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_SESSION['role']=='admin'); {
                    echo '
                    <li><a href="admin-dashboard.php" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i><span class="hide-menu">Admin Dashboard</span></a></li>
                    <li> <a class="has-arrow" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><span class="hide-menu">Horses</span></a>
                    <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                    <li><a href="add-edit-horse.php"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;New Horse</a></li>
                    <li><a href="view-all-horses.php"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;View Horses</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a class="has-arrow" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-users"></i><span class="hide-menu">Riders</span></a>
                    <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                    <li><a href="add-edit-rider.php"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>&nbsp;New Rider</a></li>
                    <li><a href="view-all-riders.php"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>&nbsp;View Riders</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a class="has-arrow" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-users"></i><span class="hide-menu">Instructors</span></a>
                    <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                    <li><a href="add-edit-instructor.php"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>&nbsp;New Instructor</a></li>
                    <li><a href="view-all-instructors.php"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>&nbsp;View Instructors</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a class="has-arrow" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-users"></i><span class="hide-menu">Grooms</span></a>
                    <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                    <li><a href="add-edit-groom.php"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>&nbsp;New Groom</a></li>
                    <li><a href="view-all-grooms.php"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>&nbsp;View Grooms</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a class="has-arrow" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><span class="hide-menu">Lessons</span></a>
                    <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                    <li><a href="view-lessons-calendar.php"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;View Lessons Calendar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="view-all-lessons.php"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;View Lessons</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a class="has-arrow" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-users"></i><span class="hide-menu">Users</span></a>
                    <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                    <li><a href="view-all-users.php"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>&nbsp;View Users</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="logout.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i><span class="hide-menu">Logout</span></a></li>
                    ';
                    }

                    if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['role']=='user'); {
                    echo '
                    <li><a href="user-dashboard.php" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i><span class="hide-menu">User Dashboard</span></a></li>
                    <li> <a class="has-arrow" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><span class="hide-menu">Lessons</span></a>
                    <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                    <li><a href="view-lessons-calendar.php"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;View Lessons Calendar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="view-all-lessons.php"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;View Lessons</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>';
                    }
                    ?>
                  </ul>
            </nav>
```

Comment: Sorry just solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way.

```
<nav class="sidebar-nav">
    <ul id="sidebarnav">
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_SESSION['role'] == 'admin') { ?>
            <li><a href="admin-dashboard.php" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i><span class="hide-menu">Admin Dashboard</span></a></li>
            <li> <a class="has-arrow" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><span class="hide-menu">Horses</span></a>
            <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
            <li><a href="add-edit-horse.php"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;New Horse</a></li>
            <li><a href="view-all-horses.php"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;View Horses</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a class="has-arrow" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-users"></i><span class="hide-menu">Riders</span></a>
            <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
            <li><a href="add-edit-rider.php"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>&nbsp;New Rider</a></li>
            <li><a href="view-all-riders.php"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>&nbsp;View Riders</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a class="has-arrow" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-users"></i><span class="hide-menu">Instructors</span></a>
            <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
            <li><a href="add-edit-instructor.php"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>&nbsp;New Instructor</a></li>
            <li><a href="view-all-instructors.php"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>&nbsp;View Instructors</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a class="has-arrow" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-users"></i><span class="hide-menu">Grooms</span></a>
            <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
            <li><a href="add-edit-groom.php"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>&nbsp;New Groom</a></li>
            <li><a href="view-all-grooms.php"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>&nbsp;View Grooms</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a class="has-arrow" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><span class="hide-menu">Lessons</span></a>
            <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
            <li><a href="view-lessons-calendar.php"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;View Lessons Calendar</a></li>
            <li><a href="view-all-lessons.php"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;View Lessons</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a class="has-arrow" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-users"></i><span class="hide-menu">Users</span></a>
            <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
            <li><a href="view-all-users.php"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>&nbsp;View Users</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="logout.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i><span class="hide-menu">Logout</span></a></li>
        <?php } ?>




        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['role'] == 'user') { ?>
            <li><a href="user-dashboard.php" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i><span class="hide-menu">User Dashboard</span></a></li>
            <li> <a class="has-arrow" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><span class="hide-menu">Lessons</span></a>
            <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
            <li><a href="view-lessons-calendar.php"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;View Lessons Calendar</a></li>
            <li><a href="view-all-lessons.php"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;View Lessons</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>


      </ul>
</nav>
```

Remember that at the beginning of the file you have to have this:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```